# Unrecognized selector sent to instance for unhiding button

Tags: swift, exception, button

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var continueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var yesButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var noButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        continueLabel.isHidden=true
        yesButton.isHidden=true
        noButton.isHidden=true        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
  
     
    @IBAction func continueButton(_sender: UIButton) {
        continueLabel.isHidden=false
        yesButton.isHidden=false
        noButton.isHidden=false
    }
    
    
}
```

I'm a bit new to IOS development and was practicing how to hide/unhide a button. On the view controller, I can get the button hidden but when I press the button to unhide - The following error is being thrown reason: '-[WelcomeApp.ViewController ContinueButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12b2061d0.

It was basically a button which displayed two options  - Yes or No. The Yes button is linked to the next view controller modally.

Comment: You can see for yourself that you view controller has no `ContinueButton`. You must have hooked up the button action in the storyboard and then changed the name in code.

Comment: Unrelated to the main issue but there must be a space character between the underscore character and `sender` in the IBAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function names, as variables, are case sensitive. You seem to have linked to `ContinueButton()` function, and then to have renamed it to `continueButton()`. Remove the link and recreate it, and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **connection inspector** as shown in the pic:

[image: connection inspector]

You can see a **yellow warning**, you have to **remove** this connection first and then again **make** the connection.